# How to develop a bar diagram (of average value) with standared error in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have following data. I want to draw a bar diagram (size of bar indicating mean) with SE of mean of category of respective variables.for example, variable height has two categories (1 and 2). I want to draw plots of all variables based on category using ggplot ?

```
Category    Variable    values
1          height   6
2          height   6
3          weight   48
2          age      67
1          age      56
2          age      43
1          age      23
1          height   6.5
1          height   7
2          age      89
1          age      65
```

Comment: Are you asking for a dynamite Plot? You'd be better off with a box plot or scatter plot instead. See: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/DynamitePlots

Comment: The data offered do not support such a plot since there is no std dev of one of the categories.That link should also explain why it is considered poor practice to use that plotting strategy.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but here's one that doesn't need any transformation of the data. As a side note, I agree with the comments about dynamite plots. May I suggest changing to `geom = "point"` instead?

*Edit: Apologies. I just noticed that you asked to have the bars separated on a second category as well. I've fixed the example below.*

```
library(ggplot2)

dd <- data.frame(
  fac = c("age", "height", "weight"),
  category = as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 3)),
  x = rnorm(27, 10, 2)
)

ggplot(dd, aes(x = fac, y = x, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean",
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_pointrange(stat = "summary", fun.data = "mean_se",
                  position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

[image]